# Вогнутый border-radius и тёмная тень в ff и safari

Tags: css3, border, css

[Есть вогнутый border-radius](http://jsbin.com/gumiyivu/1/edit).

В данном примере у документа белый фон, а другой объект залит радиальным градиентом от какого-то определённого цвета (цвет не имеет значения) к прозрачному.

В операх (Webkit и Presto) и хроме всё хорошо — вижу градиент от нужного цвета к белому фону документа. А вот лиса (Aurora) и сафари (7.0.5) грешат — в них градиент тёмный, будто в градиент промежуточным значением добавлен чёрный цвет.

1. Это баг браузера? Если да, то, наверно, уже отправили баг-репорт браузерам? И где эти баг-репорты поддержать?
2. Может есть ещё способы реализовать вогнутый border-radius без перекрытия элементами друг друга?

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/ - вот сервис для подбора градиента

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте rgba вместо transparent.

```
background: radial-gradient(circle at 0 0, rgba(255, 160, 0, 0) 69%, #ffa500);
```

http://jsbin.com/gumiyivu/3/

по поводу бага  в браузере, непонятно что ещё баг :) дело в том что если вы указываете transparent, то градиент будет от черного-прозрачного rgba(0,0,0,0) в цветной, с переходом через черный, вопрос о том как именно градиент должен считаться является хорошим  поводом для холивара.